# Getting object attribute value from URL

Tags: node.js, object, undefined

So I get some data from a websites API. I get it in the following way:

```
function httpGet(url){
  var response = requestSync(
    'GET',
    url
    );
    return response.body;
}
const listValue = JSON.parse(httpGet("URL"));
```

The gathered data basically looks like this:

```
listValue = {
    banana: "yellow",
    apple: "green",
    kiwi: "brown"
}
```

I also have another object that looks like this:

```
object = {
    'yellow': 11,
    'green': 5,
    'brown': 14,
}
```

My goal is to access the the data in *object* object via *listValue* attribute like so:

```
var color = listValue.banana;
var value = object.color;
```

But the color variable always ends up being *undefined* no matter what I do. I've tried stringifying the color variable and all sorts of things but havent figured out what's the problem. If you have a clue please let me know.

Comment: It means that `listValue` doesn't have a field `banana` and doesn't look like you described. Hard to say why without debugging or at least trying the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try accessing the object like this:

```
var color = listValue.banana;
var value = object[color];
```

Comment: It says in the question that `color` variable ends up being `undefined`. It means `listValue` doesn't have a `banana` field.

Comment: Nah it works now, and I've tried the exact same thing like 20 min ago. It wasn't working before for some reason...

Answer (score 1):

May be you can access it via ?

```
var color = listValue.banana;
var value = object[color];
```

Be sure to check if the key exists before accessing it. (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(pbj, key))